# Fetching those rows where id is different in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having below mentioned table:

```
Source     Value     e_mail               count          ID
RT-121     124566    aft.12@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-1
RT-122     124887    efyyhd@hotmail.com                  P-2
RT-123     124887    efyyhd@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-3
RT-124     484566    aft.19@hotmail.com                  P-7
RT-125     484566    aft.19@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-8
RT-126     124566    aft.12@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-1
```

I want to write a query which give me output where `Value` and `e_mail` are same and `Count` is either `Null` or blank having different `ID`.

Required Output:

```
Source     Value     e_mail               count          ID
RT-122     124887    efyyhd@hotmail.com                  P-2
RT-123     124887    efyyhd@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-3
RT-124     484566    aft.19@hotmail.com                  P-7
RT-125     484566    aft.19@hotmail.com   PR12S          P-8
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @nicomp Apparently, it is. :-(

Comment: @VectorJX . . . What is this supposed to mean:  "\Count is either Null or blank having different ID"?

Comment: @Strawberry Have you noticed that "How do I write program X" is usually downvoted into oblivion but "How do I write SQL Y" is more often answered?

Comment: @nicomp No. In my view, downvotes and close votes are drastically under-used, to the detriment of this site as a whole.

Comment: @Strawberry Note that OP posts sub-par question, gets an answer, and criticizes the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.value = t.value and
                    t2.e_mail = t.e_mail and
                    (t2.count <> '' xor t.count <> '') and
                    t2.source <> t.source
             );
```

With an index on `(value, e_mail, source)`, this is probably the fastest approach.

Comment: What about the `Count`, It should be either blank or null.